# Copying Image Data to Clipboard?

Tags: javascript

I am working on a site where the client has a coupon code image on a product page and when the user clicks on the image he wants that code copied to the clipboard... is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

With JavaScript clipboard access is pretty much disabled in all browsers unless a user enables it in their settings. The work around is using a Flash Copy to clipboard script, but Flash is getting more security restrictions set on that. Check out [zeroclipboard](http://code.google.com/p/zeroclipboard/).

Answer (score 0):

If you want the image to be copied, you can use "createControlRange()" like so:

```
var imageTag = document.getElementById("couponCode");
if (document.body.createControlRange) //to check if browser is IE
{
    var couponRange;
    document.getElementById("couponCode").contentEditable = true;
    couponRange = document.body.createControlRange();
    couponRange.addElement(imageTag);
    couponRange.execCommand('Copy');
    document.getElementById("couponCode").contentEditable = false;
    alert("Image copied");
}
else //for other browsers
{
    alert("Your browser does not allow access to clipboard.\nPlease press Ctrl+C to copy");
    var couponRange = document.createRange();
    couponRange.selectNode(imageTag);
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();
    window.getSelection().addRange(couponRange);
}
```

Browsers other than IE do not allow Javascript to access the clipboard for security reasons. But you can invoke the browser functionality by asking the user to press Ctrl+C after selecting the range of the coupon image.

Hope this solves your problem.